# Threads and sync

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization

I build a GTA program that when player is using resource no one else can use it
I tried to change priorities but this didn't seems to help.
you can see that after player4 started using guns also player3 and he shouldn't.
what I am trying to do is that when a player using an object no one else should be able to access it until the player finished.
thanks in advance!

**Resources:**

```
package GTA;
public class Resources
{
    static final Object guns = "guns";
    static final Object drugs = "drugs";
    static final Object money = "money";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Player[] p = new Player[4];
        p[0] = new Player("player1");
        p[1] = new Player("player2");
        p[2] = new Player("player3");
        p[3] = new Player("player4");
        p[0].start();
        p[1].start();
        p[2].start();
        p[3].start();
    }
}
```

**Player:**

```
package GTA;
public class Player extends Thread
{
    public Player(String name) {super(name);}
    public void run()
    {
        synchronized (Resources.guns)
        {
            System.out.println(getName() + " is using the guns");
            setPriority(7);
            
            try {   sleep(2000);}
            catch(InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
        
        synchronized (Resources.drugs)
        {
            System.out.println(getName() + " does some drugs");
            setPriority(4);
            
            try {   sleep(2000);}
            catch(InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
        
        synchronized (Resources.money)
        {
            System.out.println(getName() + " is swimming in money right now");
            setPriority(1);
            
            try {   sleep(2000);}
            catch(InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
        System.out.println(getName() + " Wasted!");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
player1 is using the guns
player1 does some drugs
player4 is using the guns
player3 is using the guns
player4 does some drugs
player1 is swimming in money right now
player3 does some drugs
player4 is swimming in money right now
player1 Wasted!
player2 is using the guns
player4 Wasted!
player2 does some drugs
player3 is swimming in money right now
player2 is swimming in money right now
player3 Wasted!
player2 Wasted!
```

Comment: You did not actually ask a question.

Comment: You should add output when a thread is done with a resource, to make the output easier to interpret. Right now we could only tell if the output is "problematic" if we knew the timing of the different messages popping up.

Comment: @dreamcrash: is there? answering questions about multithreading is hard enough. Having to guess the question in addition means it'll quickly not be worth investing the effort.

Answer (score 1):

> you can see that after player4 started using guns also player3 and he
> shouldn't.

The synchronization block will not *tell* threads to skip that block if a threads is already inside. It just *tells* the thread to wait until the other thread is finished. Therefore, in your code all threads will execute all the those three blocks protected by the `synchronized`, regardless of how long the thread stay inside that block `sleep(2000);` albeit the execution of those blocks will be performed sequentially.

If you want to limit the number of threads that can access a certain resource (e.g., execute a block of code) you need to use [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) (or alike) for that purpose.

> what I am trying to do is that when a player using an object no one
> else should be able to access it until the player finished.

If by object you mean separately the `guns`, `drugs`, `money`. Then you achieve that there will not be multiple player (*i.e.,* threads) using those objects simultaneously.

If by "after the player have finish" you mean the entire run then you need to synchronize the entire block of the `run()` method using a single lock.

Answer (score -1):

You have three monitors by three objects and each of them has a lock independently.
You should take a lock by using one monitor for object Resource.
You can try that:

```
public class Solution01 {

static final Object guns = "guns";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Player[] p = new Player[4];
    p[0] = new Player("player1");
    p[1] = new Player("player2");
    p[2] = new Player("player3");
    p[3] = new Player("player4");
    p[1].setPriority(3);
    p[2].setPriority(2);
    p[3].setPriority(1);
    p[0].start();
    p[1].start();
    p[2].start();
    p[3].start();
}

public static class Player extends Thread {

    public Player(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (Solution01.guns) {
            System.out.println(getName() + " is using the guns");
            try {
                sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(getName() + " does some drugs");
            try {
                sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(getName() + " is swimming in money right now");
            try {
                sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(getName() + " Wasted!");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I think the following is what you are looking for. If you want to limit the threads to behave in a synchronous manner when using resources, you should synchronize the access on the resource:

Resources class:

Example is only for the guns:

```
class Resources {
static synchronized void useGun(String playerName) {
    System.out.println(playerName + "is using the gun");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Player[] p = new Player[4];
    p[0] = new Player("player1");
    p[1] = new Player("player2");
    p[2] = new Player("player3");
    p[3] = new Player("player4");
    p[0].start();
    p[1].start();
    p[2].start();
    p[3].start();
}
}
```

Player class:

```
class Player extends Thread {

private String name;

public Player(String name) {
    super(name);
    this.name = name;
}

public void run() {
    Resources.useGun(name);
    System.out.println(getName() + " Wasted!");
}
}
```